# Pixel editing stuck - low cpu

Tags: android

Im running Nexus One virtual device on my eclipse and this is the problem:
I got a button and when i press it every pixel is colored (double loop) and it works just fine with small and low resolution pics but a normal picture makes it stuck for at least 15 seconds until the whole proccess finishes and the result is fine but i cant understand why it takes so long..
Its definitely about the workspace or something cause when i run this code in C# it works smoothly and it doesnt even take a half second for this action to finish.
Is there any way to make the device cpu stronger or something.. anything? xD
Thanks a lot :P

Comment: Virtual devices are slooooow..Try using a real device or try Use GPU Host.

Comment: You should use a real device for development (beware! usually developping app works good in emu but crashes on REAL device!) and if you want to use emulator than you should have an Intel CPU based PC and use special version of emulator optimized for Intel (there are gossips that this emu version works much faster).